# If I declare a vector in a C++ class, will it be destroyed then the instate of class is destroyed?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Say I have such a class

```
class A {
public:
       vector<int> intVector;
       A() {
            intVector.push_back(1);
       };
       ~A(){};
};

int main() {
        A *k = new A;
        delete k;
}
```

When A is instantiated as k, intVector will be created. However, my question is, if the destructor does not take care of intVector, will the memory allocated for intVector be recycled when the pointer of k is destroyed?

Comment: Your destructor is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will generate code inside the destructor of the class to destroy all member variables (and call any base-class destructors that a class is derived from)

Comment: Thank you! I thought about it should be delete as the variable inside the class gotten deleted, but wasn't sure how.